# $(R\setminus S)\cap \bar S=\varnothing$, then there exists a ring $\bar R$ such that $\bar S$ is a subring of $\bar R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

When learning Abstract Algebra, we encounter witha theorem:

> **Theorem 1** Let R be a ring and S the subring of R,$ \phi:S\to \bar S$ an isomorphism. If $(R\setminus S)\cap \bar S=\varnothing$, then there exists a ring $\bar R$ which is isomorphic to &$R$ such that $\bar S$ is a subring of $\bar R$.

The proof of the theorem is trivial but I wonder if it's true when we don't have $(R\setminus S)\cap \bar S=\varnothing$. I think this is true if the following statement is.

**Lemma**.$\forall$ set A,B, $ \exists  $set C s.t.$ |A|=|C|,B\cap C=\varnothing$

If it holds, then we may extend the theorem to the follows statements:

**Theorem 2** Let R be a ring and S the subring of R,$ \phi:S\to \bar S$ an isomorphism, then there exists a ring $\bar R$ that is isomorphic to $R$ such that $\bar S$ is a subring of $\bar R$.

**proof** Even if $(R\setminus S)\cap \bar S\neq \varnothing$, we can find a set $R'\ \text{s.t.} |R'|=|R|,R'\cap \bar S=\varnothing$, according to the lemma. and a bijection $f:R'\to R$，addition and multiplication in $R'$ is defined as: $$\forall a,b\in R', a\cdot b= f^{-1}[f(a)f(b)],a+b=f^{-1}[f(a)+f(b)]$$
then $R'$ is a ring ,$f:R'\to R$ is an isomorphism ,$S'=f^{-1}(S)$ is a subring of $R’$ which isomorphic to $S$ and $\bar S$.

Use the theorom 1 above on $R',S',\bar S$, then we conclude that $\bar R\cong R'$，hence isomorphic to $R$; $\bar S$ is a subring of $\bar R$ which is isomirphic to $S$.

I don't know if the proof above correct. If not, In what extent can we weaken the condition to assure the theorem holds? Feel free to point out any mistakes above.

Comment: Please also have a glance at the edited post.

Comment: I can prove the lemma. Please help me about the Algebra part.

Answer (score 1):

The Lemma is true. For example, consider
$$C = (A - B) \cup \{ (x, A, B) \mid x \in A \cap B \}.$$

The proof of Theorem 2 is correct.

Comment: Then the theorem I posted still holds for $(R\setminus S)\cap \bar S\neq\varnothing$?

Comment: @bof you're right, thank you. I made a second attempt.

Comment: @LEY yes, that proof is correct. But I would simplify the last paragraph to the following: "Use the theorem 1 above on $R′$, $S′$, $\bar{S}$, then we conclude that there is a ring $\bar{R}$ such that $\bar{S}$ is a subring of $\bar{R}$". The statement of Theorem 1 does not concern about $\bar{R}$ being isomorphic $R$, although the most natural proof of it would give a $\bar{R}$ that is isomorphic to $R$.

Comment: @ Joao Junior: We need R isomorphic to $\bar R$. That's a typo.